# Python: Using many files as input

Tags: python, python-2.7, file, input, indexing

I have program that took URLS from web pages and saved the web pages as .html files in a folder onto my desktop. Now I need to use those same .html files and set them as input into my next program. My question is how do I get all these files which are approx 400+ as the input into a function that will do the rest of the work? I am also working with python 2.7 currently but i have the newest python available if i need to use it.

Comment: `import os; os.listdir()`?

Comment: use `glob.glob("/path/to/*.html")` to list all files

Answer (score 1):

this should slove your problem
    yourpath = 'path//to//file'

```
import os
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(yourpath, topdown=False):#topdown traversing
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        stuff
    for name in dirs:
        print(os.path.join(root, name))
        stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Your second function could take a list of file names like so:

```
def process(files):
    for f in files:
        # do stuff
```

And you can obtain the list of files by doing

```
import os
files = os.listdir('/path/to/files')
```

Comment: can i still use this if my files are html? i will have to open and read them so would i still need a urlopen(files)?

Comment: Python won't care what the contents of your files are. The question is are those html files stored locally on your machine? If so, `urlopen` is unnecessary because you can just use `open` to read them.

Comment: yes i have  the files stored in a folder so im doing file =open(path) now my current issue is im trying to get only the parapraphs text and tokenize it. im using the ntlk to tokenize but first i need the correct text from paragraph tags only. i am trying beautiful soup.find_all('p')

Answer (score 0):

You can use `glob.glob()` to return all the file path names that match the pattern, and then iterate all files and process them one by one

```
html_files = glob.glob("/path/to/*html")

for html_file in html_files:
    with open(html_file) as inputs:
        for line in inputs:
            # do your work on the line
```